# ListView containing only a single item appears at the bottom

Tags: android, listview

I'm fairly new to Android and when I have a ListView containing only a single item that item appears at the bottom of the ListView. I'm assuming this is because the ListView is populated from the bottom. So, is there a way to get the ListView to populate from the top? Or are there any other methods to get the same result? Thank you.

Here is my definition of the ListView

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fileList"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/previous"/>
```

When I remove  `android:layout_above="@+id/previous` the problem is fixed, but my list extends behind the button I have at the bottom off the screen.

Comment: In my applications it usually populates from the top. Could you show us some of your code?

Comment: How do you know where is it populated from if you only have 1 element?, I mean, 1 element... has no order, it's always first and last. I imagine your element appears at the bottom of the screen or something like that, if that's the thing, I guess something is wrong in your layout file (XML). As @BertPeters said, show us some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `android:gravity` attribute in your defined `ListView` in static XML. It sounds like you may have it set to `android:gravity="bottom"`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by setting `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` to `fill_parent`

Answer (score 0):

remove this line, list will show from top.

```
android:layout_above="@+id/previous"
```